# Which iOS devices support microphone input via the headphone jack?

Tags: ios, audio

I want to use an iOS device as a field recorder for an XLR microphone. However, I need to buy an adapter to plug in the mic via the headphone port. Which iOS devices support mic input (with the third band on the jack) via the headphone port?

Comment: I am not sure on all the exact models that support it but I have used an iRig on an iPhone 3G, 4 and iPad 1 and 3.

Comment: Have you used anything besides the iRig?

Comment: No, just that make. Be aware while the older devices do support this tech, it can be painful to use if you are doing a lot. It did work on my iPhone 3G but just. I use Garage Band on my iPad 1 and have made some scratches using it and while slow, it is workable.

Comment: Ah. Okay. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a summary of what iOS devices support microphone in via the headphone jack. This information was acquired by looking at [Compatibility of Apple wired headset models with iPhone, iPad, and iPod models](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3310)

**iOS Devices that support Microphone via the headphone jack**

- iPod touch (2nd generation and later)
- iPhone (Original and later)
- iPad (Original and later)

Note: *iPod touch (2nd generation) software version 2.2 or later required to use remote and mic features.*

Comment: Some non-iOS iPods can also make use of the microphone and inline controls.

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea why I coudn't find that list! It's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, and its ok Apple's site is not the easiest place to find things on, I found it searching for specs relating to the Apple Earphones with Remote and Mic.

Answer (score 2):

All current versions of iOS devices support a microphone input via the headphone jack. The only exception I know of is iPod touch 1st Gen which does not support a microphone through the headphone jack. Also the iPod Nano is not an iOS device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I may not end up dealing with a current generation iOS devices, I really do need an exhaustive list.